# Where is google Chromium's Xcode Project?

Tags: xcode, browser, chromium, xcode-project, gn

I'm trying to make a web browser application for macOS. So I went to build chromium for macOS. I did all the instructions but I never got an Xcode project. Can you please help me with this.

I was following the instructions for macOS

Comment: Could you tell us which instructions you were following, from where? This question is a bit less specific than we usually like on Stack Overflow, and it is difficult to answer with what we've got.

Comment: I was following the macOS instructions

Answer (score 0):

You have to use GN to build XCode project. Suppose `YourBuildFolder` is the folder in which you are compiling Chromium, then execute the following command:

```
gn gen out/YourBuildFolder --ide=xcode
```

Now if you navigate to `YourBuildFolder` you should see this file: `all.xcodeproj`

As this project is too big, it will slow down XCode. So this isn't the recommended way to write Chromium code in macOS.

Comment: Right now, I'm downloading the 20gb source code.  I'll check if it works for me

Comment: @WD123 If this works then please mark it as a solution to your question

Comment: See https://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/debugging-on-os-x/building-with-ninja-debugging-with-xcode for further details on building with Ninja and debugging with Xcode.